# How do I insert a database record from an onclick event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net

How do I insert database record (MySQL) in C# and Web Forms when JavaScript onclick event is triggered on the hyperlink ?

My code below I don't have error but the record not inserted.

In HTML view the value of :

> a onclick="(<%=(rds.fields("foo").Value)%>)" href="....

is correct :

```
<a onclick="DataPrinted(CEF)" href=".... >
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

**Javascript and Web Forms code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function DataPrinted(IDNumber) {

        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "UpdateDataPrintStatus.aspx", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("ID=" + IDNumber);
    }

</script>

<a onclick="DataPrinted(<%=(rds.fields("foo").Value)%>)" 
   href="javascript:document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
   location.href='<%=rds.fields("link")%>';" target="_top" >
<%=rds.fields("foo")%>
<span>Test</span></a>
```

**UpdateDataPrintStatus.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
            string IDNumber = Request.Form["ID"].ToString();

            string query = String.Format(" INSERT INTO (IDNumber) ");
            query += String.Format(" VALUES ( ? ); ");

            using (OdbcConnection conn =
                new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OdbcCommand cmd =
                    new OdbcCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", IDNumber.ToString().ToUpper());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

**Edit #01**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('name').click(function () {

        var book_id = $(this).parent().data('id');

        $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'UpdateDataPrintStatus.aspx',
            data: { "ID": book_id },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (result) {
                $('.modal-box').text(result).fadeIn(700, function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.modal-box').fadeOut();
                    }, 2000);
                });
            }
        });
    });                 
</script>



<a id="name" data-id="<%=rds.fields.Item("foo").Value%>" 
   href="javascript:document.getElementById('loading').style.visibility = 'visible';
      location.href='<%=rds.fields("link")%>';" target="_top">
         <%=rds.fields("link")%>
            <span>test</span>
</a>
```

**UpdateDataPrintStatus.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string IDNumber = Request.Form["ID"].ToString();

            string query = String.Format(" INSERT INTO tbl ");
            query += String.Format(" (name) VALUES (?); ");

            using (OdbcConnection conn =
                new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (OdbcCommand cmd =
                    new OdbcCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Open();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", IDNumber.ToString().ToUpper());
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        cmd.Connection.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: This is not Classic ASP. This is Web Forms. Classic ASP is something different entirely.

Comment: @Satindersingh Hello. thank you so much for reply, please see **Edit #01** in my first question... I have used jquery and ajax but I can't make it...